# Can I run Wine on an Android slate?

Tags: android

I would like to run a small Windows program on an Android slate. It runs just fine under Wine in Ubuntu, but I am unsure how to install & run Wine on the Android slate.

Sorry if it's not strictly a programming question. If you want it to be so, I could rephrase it as "will I have to write my Delphi code again Java  in order to run it on an Android slate?"

Comment: This kind of question belongs in http://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it will work because you would be trying to run x86 software on a non-x86 processor.  To start you would need binaries compiled for an ARM processor.

Answer (score 2):

> but I am unsure how to install & run Wine on the Android slate.

I sincerely doubt that is possible or will be within the next decade. While Android runs a Linux kernel, most of what WINE depends upon in Linux will look very different on Android. Not to mention the opcode issue noted by JOTN.

> "will I have to write my Delphi code again Java in order to run it on an Android slate?"

Most likely. I don't know what "my Delphi code" entails. If it is pure algorithm stuff, conceivably you could use Free Pascal to get an ARM library you could link to via the Android NDK. If, however, "my Delphi code" involves the UI and the like, you would have to rewrite it (or cook up your own Delphi->Android translator) to get it to use Android's widget library.

Comment: +1 Ok, so no Wine :-(  Thanks    I'll leave this open for an hour or so and if no one contradicts you then you get the answer.  I think I might find some globabl edits that can handle 80-90% of porting from Delphi to Java (fingers crossed)

Answer (score 1):

If your windows program has any GUI, then it will definitely not work. Wine relies on an X-windows system when Android has its own graphical framework...

Comment: The program does have a Windows GUI and does run under Wine on Ubuntu.

Comment: @Mawg There is no X windowing system on Android.  Wine depends on X for the GUI parts.  No X = No GUI = No Wine

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking at something similar recently. Wine doesn't run on anything that is not x86, period. When you introduce a GUI (as noted by Matthieu), anything outside of wine will need to utilise another graphics libraries.

It might be worth mentioning wine-lib, you can use this with gcc to cross complile to ARM but you'll end up in a 'world of pain' as soon as you have a GUI. I cannot be 100% but my guess is you're in for a rewrite. http://wiki.winehq.org/ARM

If you do go for a rewrite perhaps look at other languages as Java for android is not nessarliy the same Java you'll run on your desktop. http://www.oreillynet.com/onjava/blog/2007/11/dalvik_googles_tweaked_nonstan.html

I know it's a bit of a 'fad' but you might be best looking at html5/webapp or using c/c++ and gtk/qt if you can find work-arounds.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but it is not easy and possibly too slow. The experimental process is described here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1258506

It is a multi-step process. First you get an Ubuntu system image and chroot into that. Then from there you can invoke wine to display on the local vncserver. Then you install a vncviewer app on android to view the GUI.

Your android device would need to have an x86 CPU. So far, only netbooks will work for this as I don't believe there are any tablets available with x86 and Android compatability. I would only recommend going this route for fun and experimentation -- not productivity.